# Elasticsearch is running with old java version

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I recently upgraded the elasticsearch version in a elasticsearch slave node. Still it is picking the wrong java version even though I set the `$JAVA_HOME` variable.

```
[igwuser@hbase3 ~]$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-05-01 12:06:09 +08; 11min ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 15809 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
           ├─15809 /opt/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java -Xms15g -Xmx15g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=...
           └─15893 /usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-ml/platform/linux-x86_64/bin/controller

May 01 12:06:09 hbase3.api.celcom.com.my systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
May 01 12:06:09 hbase3.api.celcom.com.my elasticsearch[15809]: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log due to Permission denied
[igwuser@hbase3 ~]$ 
[igwuser@hbase3 ~]$ 
[igwuser@hbase3 ~]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_251-amd64/
[igwuser@hbase3 ~]$
```

Comment: you look at the `JAVA_HOME` setting for your user _igwuser_.  Elasticsearch is running as a service, that means you have to set up the environment for the service user that is used by elasticsearch.

Comment: I'll check and answer tomorrow

Comment: @PradeepSanjeewa, great and let me know if you have further queries.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch: As mentioned in the description, ```JAVA_HOME``` is set to the newly installed ```jdk1.8.0_251-amd64``` version.

Comment: you are showing that JAVA_HOME is set for *your* user, not for the service

Answer (score 0):

As it's mentioned in the logs, your elasticsearch service is using the JDK present at the path `/opt/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java` while your `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_251-amd64/`.

Please make sure, that your elasticsearch service uses the correct path. Please see [this official](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html#jvm-version) information on how to set it.

**Edit** As Elasticsearch installation is done using the installer, its owned by elasticsearch user, which uses the bundled JDK mentioned in my previous link, **In order to make it work, you need to add your new JDK `JAVA_HOME` to this user but it's not trivial**,

Hence would suggest installing Elasticsearch from tarball [from this official link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/targz.html) and when you start elasticsearch now from user `igwuser` for which `JAVA_HOME` points to your lastest JDK, your Elasticsearch will also use that and you can see that in startup logs as well or in your elasticsearch process.

For example, in my case, my JAVA_HOME points to

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

And this is what printed in Elastic startup logs

> JVM home [/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64]

And same can also be verified in Elastic process by using `ps aux | grep elastic`

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
> -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true

Comment: Hi, yes I have correctly set ```JAVA_HOME``` to new version ```jdk1.8.0_251-amd64```. Please refer code I have mentioned in the question. New java version-jdk1.8.0_251-amd64. Old java version- jdk1.8.0_151

Comment: @PradeepSanjeewa did you get a chance to follow https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html#jvm-version mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @PradeepSanjeewa but not for the `elasticsearch user` which runs your es process

Comment: @PradeepSanjeewa, I would suggest you install elasticsearch using tar file which gives you all the flexibility , please follow https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/targz.html to do it

Comment: @PradeepSanjeewa also updated my answer, please have a look and feel free to comment if need further info

Comment: @PradeepSanjeewa, any luck, were u able to resolve it?

Comment: No issue is there yet.